# error : ", ".join(_PIL_INTERPOLATION_METHODS.keys())))

Tags: python

I'm training a model for image classification and I keep getting this error while training.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okw7u.png)

Comment: Please [don't post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). What you have provided in your image can be represented as text formatted as code. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73137807/edit) your post and show us text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dunno if this is overly simple but who ever is responsible for the biliniear interpolation method spelled it wrong (two Ls)

Answer (score 0):

I think you wrote "billinear". Change it to "bilinear"